# segmented control activation on tap

Tags: ios

I have this `segmented control` and I want it to activate something when one of the segments is tapped. My app already does some computation so I want the segmented control to activate only upon being tapped. I created an `if statement` to activate it but I'm not sure what to put for the conditions. Not sure if I am going about this app properly but Im just testing things here and there.

```
if (/** on tap **/){

NSArray *tipValues = @[@(0.1), @(0.15), @(0.2)];
tipAmount = billAmount * [tipValues[self.tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex] floatValue];
totalAmount = tipAmount + billAmount;
}
```

Here is the code for part of my project:

```
#import "TipViewController.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@interface TipViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *billTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tipLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *totalLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *tipControl;

- (IBAction)onTap:(id)sender;
- (void)updateValues;
- (void)onSettingsButton;

@end

@implementation TipViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Tip Calculator";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self updateValues];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onSettingsButton)];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)onTap:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES]; //keyboard goes away
    [self updateValues];
}

- (void)updateValues{
    float billAmount = [self.billTextField.text floatValue];

    float tipAmount;
    float totalAmount;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //NSString *stringValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"some_key_that_you_choose"];
    int intValue = [defaults integerForKey:@"another_key_that_you_choose"];

    if (intValue && billAmount > 0) {
        tipAmount =  .01 * intValue * billAmount;
        totalAmount = tipAmount + billAmount;
    }

    // array to hold all tip values

    if (){

    NSArray *tipValues = @[@(0.1), @(0.15), @(0.2)];
    tipAmount = billAmount * [tipValues[self.tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex] floatValue];
    totalAmount = tipAmount + billAmount;
    }


    self.tipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%0.2f", tipAmount];
    self.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%0.2f", totalAmount];

}

- (void)onSettingsButton {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[SettingsViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Updated `updateValues`

```
- (void)updateValues{
    float billAmount = [self.billTextField.text floatValue];
    //tipAmountIndex = NSNotFound;

    float tipAmount;
    float totalAmount;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //NSString *stringValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"some_key_that_you_choose"];
    int intValue = [defaults integerForKey:@"another_key_that_you_choose"];

    //self.tipAmountIndex = NSNotFound
    // array to hold all tip values

    if (self.tipAmountIndex != NSNotFound) {
        NSArray *tipValues = @[@(0.1), @(0.15), @(0.2)];
        tipAmount = billAmount * [tipValues[self.tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex] floatValue];
        totalAmount = tipAmount + billAmount;
    }else {
        if (intValue && billAmount > 0) {
            tipAmount =  .01 * intValue * billAmount;
            totalAmount = tipAmount + billAmount;
            //[self.tipControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:-1 ];
            self.tipAmountIndex = NSNotFound;
        }
    }

    self.tipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%0.2f", tipAmount];
    self.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%0.2f", totalAmount];

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to react to the tap or just want to know which segment is selected?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'm making a tip calculator and the 3 segments are 10/15/20 percent so what I want it to do is to use the values inside to calculate percentages. So know which segment is selected

Comment: And you have a method that is called when the selected segment is changed?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist actually I want to try react to the tap. What would I do for an if statement if I just wanted to react just on tap?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a target / action to the segmented control so that it tells you when the segment is changed and you can run your code. Assuming your code is in the method `refreshForPercentageChange`:

```
[self.segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshForPercentageChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

---

Specifically for your updated code, you could have a variable `tipAmountIndex`. When the user enters a specific value, set it to `NSNotFound`. If the segment is tapped, set it to the index. Then in your code you would use:

```
if (self. tipAmountIndex != NSNotFound) {
```

but this `if` should be around determining the tap multiplier only. The `else` should add the default / user set tip multiplier. Then the calculation is after (not inside) the `if`.

Comment: This sort of works but it overrides my previous function of using custom tip amounts.

Comment: This is just the trigger for you to set the tip amount to a set value and recalculate. The user could still enter a specific value (which would cause another recalculation) if you want.

Comment: I'm pretty new to iOS dev and I updated the `updateValues` function. Not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Could you take a look? thanks!

Comment: Close. I'm not sure what role `intValue` plays. Inside the `if` I would not have any calculations, just a setting, then the calculation after the `if` (using that setting for the tip percentage).